# Can we add gradient color in oxyplot graphs

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, graph, oxyplot

I have been trying to achieve gradient color for the oxyplot graphs.

Some old blogs saying that gradient color is not supported by oxyplots. Could anyone suggest any tweaks to achieve the below kind of view?

And also any suggestions are open to which graphs can be used apart form oxyplots in xamarin.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSOT5.png)

Comment: For now, the gradient and hatch brushes of `oxyplot` are not supported.

Comment: You can use Syncfusion charts. They provide free options